# Angular2: strange routing issue where url doesn't get updated and route doesn't stay persistent when the page gets reloaded

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am working on a angular2 web app.  I already have a few routes setup that all work as expected.  I recently added a Goods Received view and i'm running into a very strange error...  I added the path and component to my app.routing.ts and added a router link to my navigation Component (which is a bootstrap navbar...)   When I run my app the goods received link is displayed in the navbar and when I click on it the router navigates to the view but the link isn't displayed in the addressbar and reloading the page returns me to the previous view I was on...  Any idea what could be causing this?

my code:

app.routing.ts:

```
import {NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home/home.component';
import { CheckBarcodesComponent } from './Components/check-barcodes/check-barcodes.component';
import { SettingsComponent } from './Components/settings/settings.component';
import { StockTakeComponent } from './Components/stock-take/stock-take.component';
import { GoodsReceivedComponent } from './components/goods-received/goods-received.component';

const appRoutes : Routes = [
{path: "goodsReceived", component: GoodsReceivedComponent },
{path: "settings", component: SettingsComponent },
    {path: "checkBarcodes", component: CheckBarcodesComponent },
    {path: "home", component: HomeComponent},
    {path: "", redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: "stockTake", component: StockTakeComponent}  
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

navigation-component.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggle-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria="navbarSupportedContent"
aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="logo" src="../../../assets/pictures/TMNewLogo.gif" style="height:100px; width:200px; text-align:center;"><p class="navbar-text">Retail Mobile</p></a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['home']"><span class="glyphicon
glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
            <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['checkBarcodes']"><span class="glyphicon
glyphicon-barcode"></span> Check Barcodes</a></li>
            <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['stockTake']"><span class="glyphicon
glyphicon-folder-open"></span> Stock Take</a></li>
<li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['goodsReceived']"><span class="glyphicon
glyphicon-list"></span> Goods Received</a></li>

            <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="nav-item"><a [routerLink]="['settings']"><span class="glyphicon
glyphicon-wrench"></span> Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ok i have no idea, is there a # in the address-bar?

Comment: @Monarchis No the address-bar doesn't get updated at all when navigating to the goods received view...

Comment: Does the Browsers Console show any exceptions?
My routes are looking similar, but all works fine maybe it's an version problem of the router?

Comment: @Monarchis turns out it was a miss labeled angular2 formGroup control...  Thanks for thaking a look...